# Write ActiveQuery to get parent and child rows based on id and parent id?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have a table 'orders' that looks a bit like this:

```
order_id    parent_id    item
14056       14054        Cheese
14055       14054        Butter
14054       NULL         Bread
```

Now, when I have the order id = 14055 I want to return all rows that are related. Same if order_id = 14056 or 14054.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

**Solution 1**

Define the relations in your `Orders` model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Orders::className(), ['order_id' => 'parent_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['parent_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

And then you can run the following:

```
$data = Orders::find()
        ->from('orders orders')
        ->joinWith('parent parent')
        ->where(['parent.order_id' => 14054])
        ->all();
```

The SQL which is produced is:

```
SELECT `orders`.* 
FROM `orders` `orders` 
LEFT JOIN `orders` parent
ON `orders`.`parent_id` = `parent`.`order_id` 
WHERE `parent`.`order_id`= 14054
```

---

**Solution 2**

Without relations you can you something like this:

```
$sub_query = Orders::find()
        ->select(['order_id'])
        ->where(['order_id' => 14054]);
$query = Orders::find()->where(['in', 'parent_id', $sub_query]);
$data = $query->all();
```

---

**Solution 3**

Using nested query:

```
$sub_query = Orders::find()
        ->select(['order_id'])
        ->where(['order_id' => 14054]);
$query = Orders::find()
        ->from('orders orders');
$query->innerJoin(['parent' => $sub_query], 'orders.parent_id = parent.order_id');
$data = $query->all();
```

The produced SQL is the following:

```
SELECT `orders1`.* 
FROM `orders` `orders1` 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `order_id` FROM `orders` WHERE `order_id` = 14054
) `parent` 
ON orders.parent_id = parent.order_id
```

---

**Solution 4**

I think that also the following will work too:

Define the new `inverted` relation in `Orders` model:

```
public function getOrders1()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['parent_id' => 'order_id'])->inverseOf('orders');
    }
```

Now run the query:

```
$data = Orders::find()
        ->with(['orders1'])
        ->all();
```

More about the inverted relations [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait.html#inverseOf()-detail).